# Duda en update en sql developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Buenas tardes, una duda para hacer una actualización de un valor en una tabla es necesario hacerlo mediante un query con la instrucción Update o se puede hacer directamente en la tabla como si fuera un excel?

Disculpen mi ignorancia soy nuevo en esto

Comment: de poder si se puede, pero es correcto hacerlo asi?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: probaste hacerlo? te dio algun error? paso algo inesperado?

Comment: Gracias Magnolia, Saludos

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se puede hacer como si fuera un Excel, lo recomendable es hacerlo mediante un *query de update*.

En Toad:

```
Schema Browser > Tablas > (mi_tabla) > Data (Pestaña)
```

Query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Pd. No olvides hacer commit.

Comment: Hola. Por favor mira [answer] para mejorar tu respuesta.